# android - how can i access dropbox session from class instead of an activity

Tags: android, dropbox-api

i am new to android. I am using dropbox CoreApi for uploading files. The problem i am facing is i am not able to access dropbox session from another class or in a service.
i am doing this in order to access the session

```
 private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDBApi; 

mRequest = mDBApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(), null);
```

but when i debug `mDBApi` it the object is null. I want to upload files. Please help me how can i access the dropbox session object in class not in activity.

Comment: Please show the code where the `mdpi` is initialized. Also, by any chance, i think maybe the variable name is wrong, mDBApi or mdpi?

Comment: i am initialising this variable after declaring class